# Missing options in Feature Selection when installing SQL Server 2016 on existing server

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2016, windows-server

I have a Windows 2008R2 64-bits server that already has 2 instances of SQL Server 2008R2 installed, and working fine. I want to add a new instance, but for SQL Server 2016, while keeping the existing instances in 2008R2. When I get to the Feature Selection, there is no option to install the Database Engine, and all the rest. All I get is this screen:

[image]

I can't figure out why the "normal" feature selection doesn't appear, so that I can add a new instance. Any tips? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think Sql Server 2016 will run on a Windows 2008 R2 server.

See the requirements for OS here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx#TOP_Principal

Comment: Geez.. Tks. I should have checked that, but I never thought that it would be a problem. The could've given a warning.

Comment: Agreed - I was disappointed I couldn't install it on my Windows 7 computer too.